# Thymeleaf: Setting an arbitrary value to an arbitrary attribute

Tags: attributes, nested, expression, thymeleaf

In my `Thymeleaf` template I need to set a custom attribute to a dynamically generated value. How would I do that?

I tried `th:attr="name=value"`, but it seems to be pretty much strict about the 'value' part. For instance, I tried to generate the following attribute:

```
<div ng-init="myUrl='http://myhost.com/something'> ... </div>
```

where `http://myhost.com/something` is a dynamic part of the `ng-init` attrubute and is generated by Thymeleaf's URL expression, like `@{...}`

Any suggestions how to compose an expression that would produce the above piece of HTML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<div th:attr="ng-init='myUrl=\'' + @{http://myhost.com/something} + '\''">...</div>
```

It will output:

```
<div ng-init="myUrl=&#39;http://myhost.com/something&#39;">...</div>
```